# Docker image builing is failing for angular project

Tags: angular, dockerfile, alpine-linux, docker-image

I am trying to build a docker image for my angular project. But, its failing with below error. I have read many articles to build the angular project docker image, but non of the article helped me. Finally its failing with `/bin/sh -c` non-zero error.

> The command '/bin/sh -c npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist'
>   returned a non-zero code: 1.

My laptop having Windows 10, where docker is installed. Below is my docker file. Could you please suggest , if anything is missing here ?

**Dockerfile**

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm ci && mkdir /ng-app && mv ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist


### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine

## Copy the default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error usually happens when Docker does not have enough memory, but it can also appear if there is not enough disk space.

You can also add set

```
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
```